# asp.net core bootstrap not working when being loaded locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I am trying to use bootstrap inside an asp.net core project. I installed bootstrap with bower.

this is my bower file:

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "jquery": "2.2.0",
    "jquery-validation": "1.16.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.6",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "metisMenu": "~2.2.0",
    "slimScroll": "~1.3.7",
    "pace": "~1.0.2",
    "angular2": "1.6.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": ">= 1.7.2",
    "jquery-validation": "1.16.0"
  }
}
```

I create an mvc project and used a layout view.

This is the _layout which I am using:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - .NET Core 1.0</title>

    <!-- Add local styles, mostly for plugins css file -->
    @if (IsSectionDefined("Styles"))
            {@RenderSection("Styles", required: false)}

    <environment names="Development">
        @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />*@
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/animate.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/animate.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Wrapper-->
    <div id="wrapper" class="@Html.PageClass()">
            <!-- Main view  -->
            @RenderBody()        
    </div>
    <!-- End wrapper-->

    <environment names="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        
        @*<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>*@
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <script src="~/lib/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/pace/pace.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/script.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/pace/pace.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/script.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

My issue is that when I load bootstrap from link everything works fine but when I try to load it locally from
~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css and js from
~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js nothing works.
I have seen other post but none of them helped. Any suggestions?

Comment: this means your bootstrap files are not loading. file path should be the problem. check on browser something like localhost/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: the fact that intelisense shows the path when i type it probably means that the path is correct. furthermore i use same path for other css or script files  which works fine

Comment: Add it via the package.json file. Should work then.

Comment: try to place static files like  bootstrap, Jquery, and other script files in the web root  directory (wwwroot file in the project)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the 3.3.7 version of bootstrap on bower. I resolved it by rolling back to 3.3.6, but you might also experience success using npm instead.